# Giving new date as invalid, when passing an argument

Tags: angular, date, typescript, ecmascript-6, angular-forms

I want to compare two dates. One of the dates comes from the `input="date"` and the other is new instance of the date object.

Getting the date by data-binding from the app.component.ts, which gets its value of date from the date input.

gives the error >>>>> 
Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

```
 @Input() taskDt;
  dtArr = this.taskDt.split('-');
  taskDtform = new Date(this.dtArr[0], this.dtArr[1] - 1, this.dtArr[2]).getTime();
  currentDt = new Date().getTime();
  constructor(private render: Renderer2, private eleRef: ElementRef) { }
```

// App Component ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { ITaskDetails } from './interfaces/task-details';
import { TaskService } from './services/task.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  currentDate: {};
  taskForm: FormGroup;
  taskArr: ITaskDetails[] = [];
  taskObj: ITaskDetails = {
    title: '',
    description: '',
    date: null
  };

  constructor(private taskSer: TaskService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.currentDate = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }

  reset() {
    this.taskForm.reset();
    this.taskForm.get('date').patchValue(this.currentDate);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.taskForm = new FormGroup({
    //   'taskTitle': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    //   'description': new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    //   'date': new FormControl(this.currentDate, Validators.required)
    // });

    this.taskForm = this.fb.group({
      taskTitle: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
      date: [this.currentDate, Validators.required]
    });
    console.log(this.taskForm);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(changes);
  }
  onSubmit() {
    // this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.get('taskTitle').value;
    // this.taskObj.description = this.taskForm.get('description').value;
    // this.taskObj.date = this.taskForm.get('date').value;

    this.taskObj.title = this.taskForm.value.taskTitle;
    this.taskObj.description = this.taskForm.value.description ? this.taskForm.value.description : 'N/A';
    this.taskObj.date = this.taskForm.value.date;
    console.log(this.taskObj);


    this.taskSer.setData(this.taskObj);
    console.log({ ...this.taskObj });
    this.taskArr = this.taskSer.getdata();
    console.log(this.taskArr);

    this.taskForm.reset();
    this.taskForm.get('date').patchValue(this.currentDate);
  }

}
```

I've also tried doing this but it gives the `invalid date error`

```
  taskDtform = new Date(this.taskDt); <<<<<<<<< gives invalid date
  currentDt = new Date();
```

// this is the tasklist component where the variable taskLst is defined

```
export class TaskListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() taskLst;
  constructor() { }

 ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.taskLst);
  }

}
```

// and it is two way bound here

```
<tr *ngFor="let task of taskLst; let i = index" [taskDt]="task.date">
```

// app component html template

```
<section class="container">
  <app-task-list [taskLst]="taskArr"></app-task-list>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you passing by the parent's template the expected Input in this component by any chances ?

Comment: sorry didnt understand your question

Comment: If you're using the @Input decorator that means you're [Passing data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding), right ? If so have you checked the Parent's template ?

Comment: when Angular gives the error like >>>>> Cannot read property 'whatever' of undefined generally is about the variable is undefined (In your case this.taskDt). This is frecuenty because it is not inicializate. Tip: use a "if (variable){  variable.myfunction() }"

Comment: yes i am . and as you can see from the app components html template, i just posted. I am passing it

Comment: @Eliseo what can i initialize it to if i dont want to use the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try passing the `taskDt` to your if statement. and convert the currentDt to Iso substring just as you did in your constructor. And then compare the two.

taskDt gave error because it was not initialized. Its better to pass the property directly.

Hope it helps!

```
@Input() taskDt;  
  currentDt = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put all in a ngOnInit

```
@Input() taskDt;
taskDtform;
currentDt;

constructor(private render: Renderer2, private eleRef: ElementRef) implements onInit { }
ngOnInit()
{
     if (this.taskDt)
     {
         let dtArr = this.taskDt.split('-');
         this.taskDtform = new Date(dtArr[0], dtArr[1] - 1, dtArr[2]).getTime();
         this.currentDt = new Date().getTime();
     }
 }
```